# Repetidos Consecutivos exceptuando números de una cadena de caracteres

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo una expresión regular para no permitir más de dos caracteres repetidos consecutivos:

```
/^(?!.*(.)\1{2}).*([a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ\s0-9])+$/
```

La expresión regular me permite ingresar cadenas de caracteres como la siguiente: `rrhhoollaa2255`

Necesito mantener el esquema existente pero solo con las  letras y no con los números, es decir que la expresión regular me debe permitir lo siguiente:

```
rrtthhoollaa3333333377777777790999812222222342324325
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta expresión regular hace lo que pides, controla que no puedas poner la misma letra mas de 2 veces consecutivas, pero que si lo permita en los números, por eso no le he puesto el rango de números ya que no quieres ejercer control sobre ellos:

```
^(?!.*([A-Za-zñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ\s])\1{2}).+$
```

[Fiddle de pruebas.](https://regexr.com/4iom0)

---

Añado filtrado de caracteres para que sólo admita letras y números:

```
^(?!.*([A-Za-zñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ\s])\1{2})[A-Za-zñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ\s0-9]+$
```

[Fiddle actualizado.](http://regexr.com/4iom0)

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero la expresión también me esta permitiendo carateres especiales y no me debería permitir. Solo debe permitir números (cualquier cantidad de numeros consecutivos repetidos) y letras (máximo 2 repetidos consecutivos).

Comment: Entonces puedes añadir el filtro de los caracteres que quieres que filtre la expresión, modifico la respuesta para añadir el filtrado a ver si es lo que buscas.

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción podría ser así:

```
^(\d|(([A-Za-zñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ\s])\3?(?!\3)))+$
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://regexr.com/4iots)</kbd>

La `RegExp` valida que:

- No permitir una cadena vacía
- Permitir 0-N número consecutivos
- Permitir hasta 2 `A-Za-zñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ\s` consecutivos